# Get Reference to back arrow in a Custom SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

My class extends Android's SearchView class i.e.:

```
   public class SearchViewCustom extends android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
{
...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how in this class I can get a reference to the built in back arrow that comes up once the view is initialized.

Comment: It is possible to get that `View`, though it's a little tricky, since it has no ID, and it's only added to the hierarchy when an action `View` expands. However, if you're trying to get at it to hide it, I would mention that that won't automatically cause the `SearchView` to completely fill the width of your `Toolbar`. It looks like `Toolbar` sizes the `SearchView` based on measured width of that button, whether it's there or not, so no matter how we fiddle with it, we end up with empty space on one side.

Comment: FWIW, if that is what you're wanting to do, it turns out that it's much simpler to put your `SearchView` directly in the `Toolbar`, not as a menu item. You can align it to the right, and toggle its width parameter between wrap and match with a couple of listeners on it.

Comment: I'm just trying to style it programmatically , i.e: the color based on a light or dark them I'm implementing

Comment: Well, [here's an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KJ4H1Rh6mvfI7tnsUsmupopCimJuKrtt/view?usp=drivesdk) of how to do it with the default setup. As I mentioned, though, it's tricky, because that `View` isn't added until an action `View` expands, and an `OnActionExpandListener` doesn't really help, since `onMenuItemActionExpand()` fires _before_ that happens. My alternative suggestion might still be the better option, since you could use all your own `View`s. [Here's an example of that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WEakLF1ghJ0WGelraudisK4pKXdIS5fS/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: No problem. Btw, I just realized that I forgot to set the `OnClickListener` on the collapse button, but I think you get the idea.